# Launch browser using selenium web driver, while adding jar file I wouldn't get any option like Add external jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I also check with diffrent MacBook but it works properly and it launches the browser

here is the code and some ss.

```
    package com.Pack;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


    public class TextBoxDemo {

        //Launch the browser
        //enter valid url
        //enter data in to text box

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }   
    }
```

[image]

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver at
>   com.Pack.TextBoxDemo.main(TextBoxDemo.java:16) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) .

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
 at com.Pack.TextBoxDemo.main(TextBoxDemo.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
 ... 1 more

Comment: I also attached picture that I am not able to Add External jar files

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the jar?
If you work in intellij you could try it via project settings so the jar is added to the classpath. Then it will be recognized.